# Unit test for creation object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm started to learn unit test using jasmine. And maybe someone can explain me - how I need to check creating new object like:

```
const outLog = {
  time: newTime,
  request: {
    direction: 'OUT',
    method: data.request.method,
    title: data.request.url,
    body: data.request.data,
    headers: getHeaders(data.request.headers),
  },
  response: {
    status: '',
    headers: {},
    body: {},
  },
};

if (data.response && data.response !== null) {
  outLog.response.status = data.response.status;
  outLog.response.body = data.response.data;
  outLog.response.headers = getHeaders(data.response.headers);
}

log.out.push(outLog);
```

Do I need to fill the fields like request method, request title with real data and check

```
const outLog = {
  request: {
    method: 'POST',
    title: 'title',
    ...
    ...
  },
}
```

expect(outLog.request.method).toEqual('POST');
   expect(outLog.request.title).toEqual('title');

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For checking objects, most frameworks usually provide some sort of pretty diff when you compare two objects.

To get this you'd first need to compare it to an object literal:

```
expect(outLog).toEqual({
   request: {
     method: 'POST',
     title: 'title',
     ...
})
```

This also removes a LOT of logic from all the expect statements, which should help with maintenance and debugging.  Additionally, when there are many different assertions, the earlier ones mask the later ones, creating unnecessary feedback loops, when the same thing could be accomplished with a single assertion.  one of the unit testing thought leaders addresses this by recommending that unit tests should only ever have a [single assertion](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/06/testing-one-assertion-per-test.html) to help keep them focused, reduce debugging time, and make them easier to work on and understand.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for explanation! Do I need to define outLog before I expect it? Thanks!